# Pass array to a page that needs access in future without an HTTP Get

Tags: angular

I have form pages that go to one page to the next about 15 in all.  I have been using query parms to pass data from one to the next in the chain. For each form, I save via a post to the database before going to the next.

Now I have an array that will be needed by a form after three steps.

I can simply query the database for the data but I was wondering if there is an angular2 way of making the array available to a subsequent form that needs to use it.

Comment: Yes. Store the state in a service before going to the next page, and have the next page load the state from the service. But keep making sure the next page still works fine if the state isn't there in memory, for example if the user refreshes the page.

Comment: I see. I was leaning to do a get request to get the data. Its not big deal but best to do that so as to gaurd against page refreshes.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have created the logic like this:

```
page1 --> fill form --> page2 --> fill form --> .. --> page 15
```

But, as you asked is it possible via angular2, the answer is yes absolutely.

But before angular2, the logic must be as simple as like this:

```
<-->On a single page<-->

step1 --> show form via JS --> user fills and submits --> save or get responses with AJAX requests to server --> show form 2 --> user fills again --> again communicate with server via AJAX requests --> ... ---> user fills final form (still the same page) --> submit form to server, or, communicate with server via AJAX, redirect user to proper page.
```

So this can be done via JavaScript, angular or Angular2 but the logic will remain.